# Facebook Feed Dialog not showing Picture

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using the feed dialog, and the picture that I'm trying to use isn't showing. The dialog comes up with the correct description and caption, but no picture.

Here's my javascript:

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: message,
    description: "...",
    caption: "...",
    link: "http://our_domain.com", 
    picture: "https://picture_stored_on_aws"
  },
  (response) ->
    window.close()
)
```

However, it works when I use a picture stored elsewhere, like this sample from the Facebook dev site: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg'.

I tried removing the https, and still no picture. Anyone else come across this problem? Does it have anything to do with referencing a picture on aws?

Comment: Can you give the URL of a sample file in the same S3 bucket as the original one? Does the original file exist in S3?

Comment: yes. here it is: https://rendezgroup-dev.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/event/image/52/thumb_pic.jpg?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJN5OQTDUW77YKBMQ&Signature=h7PkBVTb5of8J8DvlWPGZGyGqJI%3D&Expires=1350549902.

Comment: so it looks like that url has an expiration on it. One of its params is 'expires'. I wonder if that has anything to do with it. Is there a way to get an image from s3 without an expiration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out, the link you received in S3 has an expiration because the file is not available for the public, only for your own account. You would have to make your image public to use it in your Facebook Feed Dialog.

Log in to the AWS Console, go to S3, find and click on the file you want to use, click on "Properties" button at the top right. You will see a window at the bottom of the page. Click on the "Permissions" tab and make sure that there is a permission for "Open/Download" for "Everyone". When you switch back to the "Details" tab then, you will see a link that is public. With this image link, the picture should also show in your Facebook Feed Dialog.

Comment: I did this, but it still wasn't working because fetching the image from S3 still gave me the url of the image with an expiration on it. To get it to work, I parsed the url to get rid of all the params (everything after the '?', which included the expiration as well as an access key and signature). The image was public, so the params weren't needed anymore, but they were blocking the picture being loaded into the Facebook feed dialog.

Answer (score 1):

It may be use of **https** , test with **http** image URL in array

```
FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'feed',
    name: message,
    description: "...",
    caption: "...",
    link: "http://our_domain.com", 
    picture: "http://picture_stored_on_aws"
  },
  (response) ->
    window.close()
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the exact same problem using Django-storages with S3Boto backend. What solved if for me was removing all the GET parameters so if your original generated S3 link was:

`https://[your account].s3.amazonaws.com/yourpic.jpg?Signature=[...]&Expires=[...]&AWSAccessKeyId=[...]`

you need to parse it to:

`https://[your account].s3.amazonaws.com/yourpic.jpg`

This worked for me, I hope it helps someone else.