# Thumbnail Image is not shown in FBDialog Sharing in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I try to post on FB through Dialog Box.

**But my picture is not shown as an thumbnail in Dialog box.**
When I posted, the Image is shown on Web but not shown in Dialog Box.

My code is as follow:

```
    FBShareDialogParams *params = [[FBShareDialogParams alloc] init];
        params.link = [NSURL URLWithString:[Dict objectForKey:@"url"]];
        params.name = [Dict objectForKey:@"name"];
        params.caption = [Dict objectForKey:@"dicription"];
        params.picture=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/appicon/facebook-share-logo.png"];
        params.description = [Dict objectForKey:@"dicription"];

if ([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWithParams:params])
        {
            /*
            [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithLink:params.link
                                             name:params.name
                                          caption:params.caption
                                      description:params.description
                                          picture:params.picture
                                      clientState:nil
                                          handler:^(FBAppCall *call, NSDictionary *results, NSError *error)
             {
                 if(error)
                 {
                     // An error occurred, we need to handle the error
                     // See: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ios/errors
                     //NSLog(@"%@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error publishing story: %@", error.description]);
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     // Success
                     //NSLog(@"result %@", results);
                 }
             }];
}
```

I also refer this link: [Same Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12948475/facebook-feed-dialog-not-showing-picture)

But still not able to solve.

**Help me to solve this.**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this one :

```
SLComposeViewController *Facebooksheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
[Facebooksheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
[self presentViewController:Facebooksheet animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Please add Social.Framework framework.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But I am using Dialog box of Native app.